# How to collect values of checkboxes in angular2?

Tags: angular

```
<input type="checkbox" name="something" *ngFor="#checkbox of checkboxes" value="checkbox.value">
```

I am using angular2.
I have many checkboxes named "something".
And I want to collect values of these checkboxes checked.

Comment: `ngModel` didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways by which you can get values of checked checkboxes those are using javascript and using angular's method here like this:-

```
<!-- using javascript method -->

<div *ngFor='#checkk of arrayCheck'>
  <input type='checkbox' [id]="'check'+checkk.key11" (change)="updateChecked(checkk.key11)">{{checkk.key11}}
</div>

<!-- Using Angular's Method -->
<div *ngFor='#no of demo2'>
  <input type='checkbox'  (change)="updateChecked2(no,$event)">{{no}}
</div>

updateChecked2(value,event){
    if(event.target.checked){
      this.demoChk.push(value);
    }
    else if (!event.target.checked){
      let indexx = this.demoChk.indexOf(value);
      this.demoChk.splice(indexx,1);
    }
    console.log(this.demoChk)
  }
```

Working example of checkbox's value <kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mIj619FncOpfdwrR0KeG?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: The approach is simple and effective. But I also had "Select all" checkbox where all are selected when I add that updateChecked2 method is not working properly.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" id="allUsers" name="allusers"  value="allusers" (click)="toggleSelect($event)">`     this is the toggleSelect function       
     ` this.communityUsers.forEach(function(item){ item.selected = event.target.checked; });`

Comment: I want to get the checked items without (click) as it is unable to fetch already checked items. Can you anser my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975524/how-to-pass-all-checked-checkboxes-from-html-to-component-of-a-form-onsubmit-i